# Google Docs Spreadsheet ImportHtml() with Basic Auth

Tags: google-sheets, importhtml

Within a Google Docs spreadsheet, I need to access external data that requires basic authentication.  Usually I would include external data by putting this in a cell:

```
=ImportHtml("http://somedomain.com/somepath", "table", 0)
```

For basic auth, I have tried a standard URL with credentials:

```
=ImportHtml("http://user:pass@somedomain.com/somepath", "table", 0)
```

Google responds with the following:

> error: Data temporarily unavailable

Is there any way to use basic auth-protected resources in a Google spreadsheet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ImportHTML](https://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?answer=155182) does not support authentication. The data has to be publicly available for you to use this function.

This applies to [ImportXML](https://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?answer=155184) & [ImportFeed](https://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?answer=155181) also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [import.io](http://import.io). They have a feature called authenticated extractor. It creates an API from the page and provides you the code to ping it from the sheet.

Comment: Could you point to documentation on this?  I installed the import.io app, accessed an authenticated page, but I got the error "The API failed to publish."  Either way it's not clear to me where the Google sheets code is provided.

Answer (score -1):

I'm looking for some solution here too. Have yet to investigate this enough but perhaps:
https://developers.google.com/secure-data-connector/docs/1.3/tutorials/spreadsheets

Comment: The secure data connector is only useful for documents you have behind a firewall.  That won't get you around a normal HTTP request with basic auth.